# How to get a div via PHP?

Tags: php, dom, parsing, html

I get a page using `file_get_contents` from a remote server, but I want to filter that page and get a DIV from it that has class "text" using PHP. I started with `DOMDocument` but I'm lost now.

Any help?

```
$file = file_get_contents("xx");
$elements = new DOMDocument();
$elements->loadHTML($file);
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if( !is_null($element->attributes)) {
        foreach ($element->attributes as $attrName => $attrNode) {
            if( $attrName == "class" && $attrNode== "text") {
                echo $element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have loaded the document to a [`DOMDocument`](http://fr.php.net/domdocument) instance, you can use XPath queries on it -- which might be easier than going yourself through the DOM.

For that, you can use the **[`DOMXpath`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)** class.

For example, you should be able to do something like this :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="text"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->textContent);
}
```

*(Not tested, so you might need to adapt the XPath query a bit...)*

Comment: a warning still produced Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 5 don't know why

Comment: Maybe a problem in your document ? Still, if it's loaded properly, you could use the `@` operator *(see http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php )* to silence that error. Note : using that operator is not a good pratice, and you should it as rarely as possible !

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I like [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
include "lib.simple_html_dom.php"

$html = file_get_html('http://scrapeyoursite.com');
$html->find('div.text')->plaintext;
```

Pretty simple, huh? It accommodates selectors like jQuery :)

Comment: Thanks @maček.. It might have been ages that you posted this, but I just needed something just like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple_html_dom like here [simple_html_dom doc](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

or use my code like here :

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('www.yoursite.com');
$con_div = $html->find('div',0);//get value plaintext each html
```

echo the $con_div in plaintext..

```
$con_div->plaintext;
```

it's mean you will find the first div in array ('div',0) and show it in plaintext..
i hope it help you :cheer