# How to get value contentEditable in PHP

Tags: php, email, contenteditable

How we can get the content present in contentEditable in html format in PHP

For example i have this code and want to get its value in a variable in PHP:

```
<div contentEditable="true"> type here
<img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCze-mfukcuvzKk7Ilj2zQ0CS6PbOkq7ZhRInnNd1Yz3TQzU4e&t=1" /></div>
```

​
because i want to use this as html body for an email.

Infact i want to get the value of contentEditable and save it into a variable and then use that variable as a body for my email. Any idea how to perform this task.

Comment: Why don't you use a form field instead of a div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to store the contents of the element in a form element so it can be submitted to your PHP page.

I assume you want `contenteditable` instead of `textarea` for rich text... consider taking a look at WYSIWYG editors like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) instead.

If you still want to stick with your current method, you'll need some JS to copy the value of the div into a hidden form element before the page gets submitted.

HTML

```
<div id="emailcontent" contenteditable>asdf</div>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="a" name="a"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $("#a").val($("#emailcontent").html());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ororof)

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('action','some.php');
form.setAttribute('method','POST');
form.setAttribute('target','_self');
form.setAttribute('enctype','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
form.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="emailData" value="'+
                     document.getElementById('yourdivid').innerHTML+'" />';
form.submit();
```

Then in your php retrieve `POST`ed data:

```
$data = $_POST['emailData'];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP maybe you can try to use php DomDocument
this is some example maybe same with want you want

[How can I get a div content in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491598/how-can-i-get-a-div-content-in-php)

[How to get a div via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567975/how-to-get-a-div-via-php)

or you can use javascript and jquery to do that