# which form tags values of HTML can be passed in get method?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Iam a noob in HTML.
which form tags values of HTML can be passed in get method through urls out of

```
<input><textarea><button><select><option><optgroup><fieldset><label>
```

like here `<select name="sort_by">
    <option value="relevance">relevance</option> </select>` sort_by can be passed as a variable to an action url using get method.

I want to pass some variables that a jquery is computing through url, for example `var min;var max;`

```
<div id="min_price" name="min_price" value="200"></div>
```

this div is inside a form and it is not possible to send the value of this div to the url, what are the possible  html tags values that can be sent using GET method in url?
I am a new noob to HTML any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: `<optgroup><fieldset><label>` don't hold values.

Comment: _and it is not possible to send the value of this div to the url_, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all tags can be sent in GET method on form submit except `<optgroup><fieldset><label><div>`(mentioned in your question)

in url you will see them as `key=value&key=value` pairs

for `<option>`, its sent in the name of `<select>`

Comment: I have this form `<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/ksaprice" method="GET">` and this div `<div id="min_price" name="min_price" value="200"></div>`  inside the form. when I am submitting it, in the url **http://127.0.0.1:8000/ksaprice/?filter=extra&sort_by=relevance** the div tag name is not appearing..

Comment: take a hidden field, add value to that and send the value

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915497/send-value-of-div-on-form-submit) for more info.

Comment: Glad to help you...consider accepting the answer if it was helpful:)