# How to update contenteditable values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to use the `contenteditable` feature to enable users edit their content without leaving their currect page. So I have the following script, it's a little messy but not very hard to understand. (I'm using CodeIgniter BTW):

```
<h3 contenteditable="true" id="title">
        <?= $display['title'] ?>
</h3>

<p id="language" value="<?= $display['lang_id'] ?>" class="text-muted">
    <span class="label label-primary">
        <a href="#" class="dark-anchor"><?= $display['lang_name'] ?></a>
        <a onclick="toggleLanguageSelection()" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </span>
</p>

<p class="text-muted">
    // By <a href="<?= base_url() ?>me"><?= $display['username'] ?></a> in <?= date('F d, Y', strtotime($display['created_date'])) ?>
</p>
<p class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Hint</strong>: You can edit description and the code directly or click the "Edit" button below.
</p>

<p class="operations">
    <a href="" class="dark-anchor" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <a href="" onclick="confirm('Are you sure to delete this snippet? FOREVER???');" class="dark-anchor" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
</p><hr />
<p contenteditable="true" id="description">
    <?= $display['detail'] ?>
</p>
<div id="content"><?= $display['content'] ?></div>

<form method="post" action="#">
    <script>
        document.write('<input type="hidden" name="title" value="' + document.getElementById('title').innerHTML + '" />');
        document.write('<input type="hidden" name="description" value="' + document.getElementById('description').innerHTML + '" />');
        document.write('<textarea name="content" style="display: none;">' + document.getElementById('content').innerHTML + '</textarea>');
    </script>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the controller (action file):

```
// testing, gives the same results after edit
echo $_POST['title];
echo $_POST['description'];
echo htmlentities($_POST['content']);
```

I used the method explained here in the second answer: [How to get value contentEditable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526675/how-to-get-value-contenteditable-in-php) (I used `write()` instead of `innerHTML`). But the value of the hidden inputs don't change. How do I "update" them when submitted?